# Send terminal commands to all other terminal windows in git bash

Tags: linux, ssh, git-bash

At work we have a load balancer with 3 servers and every time some changes need to be made, I have 3 terminal windows opened in git bash with SSH connections to these and I must run the same commands on each window one after the other.

I know this is not optimal but our setup is like this for the moment and I can't change anything about it.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to "link" or pipe these SSH connection terminals so when I write commands (in one of the terminal windows or a 4th terminal "master" window) for example a "tar" command or "ls", these are executed on each server and I can see the output on each to compare and save a lot of time?

Comment: What about a script to make connections to servers one by one and send your command?

Comment: That would not do as unfortunately I need to do some monitoring and check the servers' status, files, etc. So it would never be the same commands

Comment: Also see [How to 'hash -r' and refresh all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398028/56041)